# Combine the first two letters of each word in a sentence string and a numeric variable

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame with 8 variables and I need to create a new column that represents a combination of two columns for use as an ID for each observation. The two columns that I need to combine look like this:

```
Aut <- c("Robert Lucas", "Finn Kydland & Edward Prescott", "Alan Blinder & Ben Bernanke", 
       "Lars Svensson & Lawrence Christiano & Robert Lucas", "Ben Bernanke")
Year <- c(1976, 1989, 1983, 1985, 1983)
df <- data.frame(Aut, Year)
```

The resulting ID variable I expect is:

```
Aut                                  Year                      ID
Robert Lucas                         1976                    RoLu1976
Finn Kydland & Edward Prescott       1989                  FiKyEdPr1989
Lars Svensson & Lawrence Christiano  1983                LaSvLaChRoLu1983
& Robert Lucas
Alan Blinder & Ben Bernanke          1985                  AlBlBeBe1985
Ben Bernanke                         1983                    BeBe1983
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(stringr)
# first split the individual names using "&" as pattern.
a <- str_split(df$Aut, "&")
# Then use lapply, split and sub to split first and last name. Then paste the 
# first two letters of each name together. 
a1 <- lapply(a, function(x){
  x1 <- str_split(str_trim(x), " ")
  paste0(unlist(lapply(x1, str_sub,1,2)), collapse="")
})
# Finally add the years. Resulting vector can be saved in df. 
df$ID <- paste0(unlist(a1), df$Year)
```

And everything together in one function:

```
foo <- function(a, b){
   a <- str_split(a, "&")
   a1 <- lapply(a, function(x){
           x1 <- str_split(str_trim(x), " ")
           paste0(unlist(lapply(x1, str_sub, 1, 2)), collapse="")
          })
   paste0(unlist(a1), b) 
}

foo(df$Aut, df$Year)
[1] "RoLu1976"         "FiKyEdPr1989"     "AlBlBeBe1983"     "LaSvLaChRoLu1985" "BeBe1983"
```

A tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = stringi::stri_extract_all_words(df$Aut) %>% 
               map(str_sub, 1, 2)  %>% 
               map_chr(paste, collapse = "")) %>% 
  unite(new, new, Year, sep="")
                                                 Aut              new
1                                       Robert Lucas         RoLu1976
2                     Finn Kydland & Edward Prescott     FiKyEdPr1989
3                        Alan Blinder & Ben Bernanke     AlBlBeBe1983
4 Lars Svensson & Lawrence Christiano & Robert Lucas LaSvLaChRoLu1985
5                                       Ben Bernanke         BeBe1983
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea:

```
library(stringi)
lst <- sapply(stri_extract_all_words(df$Aut), function(x) substr(x, 0, 2))
df$ID <- paste0(sapply(lst, function(x) paste(x, collapse = '')), df$Year)
```

Which gives:

```
#                                                 Aut Year               ID
#1                                       Robert Lucas 1976         RoLu1976
#2                     Finn Kydland & Edward Prescott 1989     FiKyEdPr1989
#3                        Alan Blinder & Ben Bernanke 1983     AlBlBeBe1983
#4 Lars Svensson & Lawrence Christiano & Robert Lucas 1985 LaSvLaChRoLu1985
#5                                       Ben Bernanke 1983         BeBe1983
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `gsub` and `paste`

```
df$ID <- with(df, paste0(gsub("(([A-Za-z]{2})[a-z& ]*)", "\\2", Aut), Year))
df$ID
#[1] "RoLu1976"         "FiKyEdPr1989"     "AlBlBeBe1983"   
#[4] "LaSvLaChRoLu1985" "BeBe1983"
```